# Subversion commits not appearing in repo

Tags: svn

Good morning to all.

I am just starting with subversion and need some help.

I have setup a repo on my server for my web directory. Steps followed are:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repo
```

Then I import the project with:

```
svn import /my/webserver/dire file:///path/to/repo
```

and start the server with

```
svnserve -d
```

Everything works fine and I can download the repo from my client with:

```
svn co svn+ssh ://user@server:/path/to/repo
```

Now on my client I edit foo.html and add a file called test. I add the file to svn with

```
svn add test.
```

Finally I commit the changes with

```
svn commit.
```

The log popups up with the changes and additions, I confirm and I get the message that test is being uploaded.

The problem is that when I log into the server and check `/path/to/repo` I do not find the new `test` file and the edited `foo.html` file.

Am new to subversion so I need some help. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy at `/path/to/repo` is the repository itself, the structure of which only makes sense to subversion and will not directly contain the file you commit.

To have the server get copy of the contents of the repo, you will want to do a checkout on the server as well:

```
svn co file:///path/to/repo /path/to/checkout
```

Then once changes are made by a client to the repo, you can bring the checked out copy up to current with..

```
svn up /path/to/checkout
```

Comment: Thanks. So basically the original source will never change and `/path/to/checkout` will always be the latest version once i decide to commit any changes done by me or others?

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni You'll always need to run `svn update` (`up` for short) on a checked out copy in order for it to get the latest changes that have been committed - you can set up a cron for this if you'd like it to always be up to date.